# Probability that M boxes are in position out of N ordered boxes

Tags: permutation, probability, combinatorics

Suppose, there are `N` ordered boxes `(Box1, Box2, Box3, ... , BoxN)`. My question is, what is the probability of the event that strictly only M boxes are in their rightful position? (M boxes need not be contiguous).

For example, there are three boxes, ie N=3. Permutations are:

`([Box1,Box2,Box3]  [Box1,Box3,Box2]  [Box2,Box1,Box3]  [Box2,Box3,Box1]  [Box3,Box1,Box2]  [Box3,Box2,Box1])`

If `M=1`, the favourable outcomes are `([Box1,Box3,Box2] [Box3,Box2,Box1] [Box2,Box1,Box3])`. Hence, probability that strictly only one box is in its rightful position = `3/6`.

I'll appreciate any help. I just can't find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine the probability inductively, based on the first slot holding the correct item or not: `p(n,m) = (1/n)*p(n-1,m-1) + ((n-1)/n)*p(n-1,m)`.

Comment: There are two ways that N slots can have M matches: Either the first slot matches and the other N-1 slots have M-1 matches, or the first slot does not match and the other N-1 slots have M matches. The equation above simply calculates and adds the two.

Comment: Thanks for the really fast reply. I've understood the equation. But how would you find the base case p(n,0)? I suppose p(0,m) = 0 or is it 1?

Comment: You know, I can't really think of a really elegant set of base cases, except p(0,0) = 1 and p(n,-1) = 0. Unpleasant putting the negative number in there. But there you go.

Comment: sorry, the third base case is p(n,m)=0 where n<m.

Comment: Incidentally, I'm 90% sure that this has some closed form which doesn't require O(n*m) computation. I just can't think of it offhand.

Comment: Your equation seems convincing. I tried to find P(3, 1) just like in the example mentioned in the question. The simplified expression came out to be : [{P(2,0) + P(1,0)}/3] + [P(1,1)/2]. According to the example, the final value should be 3/6 = 1/2. (P(1,1) = 1 (makes sense), that means left P(2,0) and P(1,0) should both be zero. However, P(2,0) isn't zero. It's rather 1/2 since there exists an outcome Box2,Box1 for M=0. Please help.)

Comment: On reflection, I don't think my equation is correct. It doesn't account for the greater probability of later matches if there are fewer early matches.

Comment: Phew, in any Dynamic Programming test cases, I couldn't find any solution base case pattern. Although your equation looks quite convincing, I believe there must be some different way of solving it.

Comment: wow, That is exactly what I was looking for. THANKS A LOT! didn't see your link before commenting.